# Unable to write entries in Cassandra when 2 out of 3 nodes down

Tags: c++, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm inserting data in Cassandra via C++. I've got 2 datacentres and total 3 nodes distributed among the 2 datacentres(dc1 and dc2). As I'm doing some experiments, so I've stopped Cassandra on 2 of the nodes. Now when I try to write data into the one remaining node, I get errors like "no hosts available". Since in the C++ program, I've not mentioned any consistency for the write statement, then why is it not working. I had read that the default write consistency was local one, therefore I should be able to write data even when only one out of 3 nodes is up.

dc1 has 2 nodes and dc 2 has 1 node.
replication strategy: network topology, dc1: 2, dc2: 1
Cassandra: 3.0.14
RHEL 6

Edit: The problem was sorted out after I changed 2 things and restarted my cluster:
1. I configured the cassandra-topology.properties. Initially it was not set with the right values.
2. I synced the time between the 3 nodes.
I don't know which one(if not both) solved the problem.

Comment: What replication factor are you using?

Comment: It might take default consistency level from schema level. Please share more details with your CQL statements.

Comment: Which two nodes did you shut down?

Comment: It doesn't matter which 2 nodes I shut down. I'm unable to enter data if only one node is up i.e. it requires 2 nodes to enter data.

Comment: @VishalSharma but what RF are you using on each DC?

Comment: I had already mentioned. dc1: 2 and dc2: 1. This is what I've defined in the keyspace.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RF does not matter for this problem. It depends on the write CL. I assume your write CL is LOCAL_ONE. Since you have only 1 up-node, it may be on dc1 or dc2. If your up-node is in dc1, since dc1 has two nodes, the hash-ring is shared by these two nodes. So, Cassandra should determine which node to write in dc1. Cassandra computes the hash of your data's partition key. If the up-node is the owner of that partition, the write succeeds, otherwise it fails.

If your up-node is in dc2, since dc2 has only 1 node, that node owns all the data. So the write should always succeed.

Comment: So you disagree with the previous answer? Also, according to you, each datacenter owns the whole hash-ring?

Comment: Yes I disagree with the previous answer and yes each datacenter owns the whole hash ring. They may even have different replication factors.

Answer (score 0):

If the keyspace you are writing to is set with RF > 1, than it means the data must be written in more than 1 replica (more than 1 node) and since only 1 node remains active, that does not satisfy the RF settings.

I assume this is the reason for the error you see.

Comment: even if I had put consistency as one/local one?

Comment: Yes, as CL=one satisfies the client but does not satisfies the RF setting across your Cassandra cluster. Think of CL as client minimal condition setting and RF as the server side minimal condition setting.

Comment: With local_one it should work but it depends on which is your local dc.@VishalSharma it would be interesting to know exactly which nodes you turned off.